# Comparison between IBM MobileFirstPlatform V7.1 and V8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

What is major difference between MFP V7.1 and V8.0.
I am trying to explore Mobilefirstplatform on Bluemix, before that I wanted to understand the enhancements of V8.0

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of what's new in MFP 80:

1) [What's new](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/whats-new/)

2) [Discontinued/Deprecated features](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/deprecated-discontinued/)

Feature list comparison across versions:

[MobileOS to feature mapping across versions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422)